# How can environment variables be retained between commands run by a single call to SSH?

Tags: bash, ssh, environment

I am attempting to run a command of the following form:

```
ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no lxplus0035 "source ~/analysis/analysis/util/setup_analysis.sh nonInteractive; time run_analysis configuration1.txt configuration2.txt"
```

The sourced script `setup_analysis.sh` sets up a complex environment including environment variables. It itself sources a script to do some of this. The executable `run_analysis` should be known to the environment after sourcing `setup_analysis.sh`.

If I do this in the local shell, it works fine and the executable launches without a problem. If I do it via the SSH command shown above, the sourcing appears to work (and I do a `which run_analysis` within the sourced script, which prints the correct executable and its path), but then after the sourcing, the executable cannot be found and run.

Why is the remote shell behaving differently and how can I get it to retain the environment set up by the sourced script?

Comment: Is `run_analysis` an executable or is it an alias?

Comment: are the variables exported?

Comment: @EtanReisner It is an executable.

Comment: @kAlmAcetA Some variables are exported, yes.

Comment: Nothing should need to be exported for the running shell to see it. That's for spawned processes. I assume the setup is setting `PATH`? Do you see the modified value of `PATH` after the source command correctly?

Comment: If you add `set -x` before the `source` command do you see the script running correctly on the remote machine?